# How to convert string to date in defined format based on defined conditions in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1
------
20002211
19980515
```

- First four values are year
- Next two values are month
- Next two values are day

And I need to replace values to 19000102 in "col1" if values concerning month are not from range 1- 12, because we have 12 months :)

Then I need to convert this string to date, so as a result I need as below:

```
col1
--------
1900-01-02
1998-05-15
```

Because in the first row was: 20002211, and month values was 22 and we have only 12 months in our calendar.
Second row was correct

Comment: `df.loc[df['col1'].str.slice(4,6).astype(int).gt(12), 'col1'] = '19000102'
pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], format='%Y%m%d') ` it probably help you replace and convert

Comment: by using first row of your code I have error: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer but I do not have any NaN in my col1 ?????

Comment: you may get onewhich is from slice you can fill with '0' `df.loc[df['col1'].str.slice(4,6).fillna('0').astype(int).gt(12), 'col1'] = '19000102' `

Comment: first line of your code works, but now with second line is problem because I have error: ValueError: time data '20130010' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match) So I forget that 00 is also bad month, how to manage with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_dateime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `errors='coerce'` as parameter.

> If ‘coerce’, then invalid parsing will be set as NaT.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce') \
      .fillna('1900-01-02')

0   1900-01-02
1   1998-05-15
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```